# image filling only one page

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a front page with an image that fills the whole page with no white spaces. Some text and links will be on top of it. At first, I tried reaching it by making a simple image tag with a class to give the needed attributes using css (z-index etc.), but It didn't work out because im not at all experienced.

Now I'm trying to do the same using the background-element. The problem is that I'm not able to restrict it only to the front page without it losing its settings. Is there an easy fix or should i just try an another approach?

HTML Code

```
<img class="home" src="patsas.jpg" />

<h1> some <br> text  </h1>
```

CSS Code

```
body.home { 
              background: url(patsas.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              -o-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you @GolezTrol! This really cleared things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues. First of all your image is not terminated, making the html invalid. Secondly, `body.cover` matches the body element, and only if it has the class 'cover'. It will never match the image.

For the final solution, I wouldn't use an `<img>` at all, but just a `<div>` that has a background image:

```css
.cover {
  /* Make the element cover the entire viewport */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  /* Set the background image to cover the entire element */
  background: url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150) center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  /* Make it stay put, if you want to.. This part wasn't really clear. */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML is as simple as a div -->
<div class="cover"></div>
```